# How to get return rowcount from stored proceedure - SQL Server 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, rdbms

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and facing problem while reading the number of rows that the stored procedure will return after matching all the conditions and join criteria.

My stored procedure is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(crs.CourseId) OVER() AS Recordcounts, 
    crs.CourseId,
    crs.CourseName,
    crs.CourseDescription,
    (SELECT CourseGroupName FROM CourseGroup cgrp 
     WHERE cgrp.CourseGroupId = crs.CourseGroupId) AS Category
FROM 
    Courses crs 
INNER JOIN 
    CourseRequests creq ON crs.CourseId = creq.CourseId
WHERE
    crs.Coursename <> ''''
```

It is returning 16 as "Recordcounts" for one of condition, but in actual, the result is 3 rows only.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Below screenshot will give more clear idea about problem for one of condition:[image]

Comment: I did not get you. If its returning more records than expected, then there is something wrong with the query. How does SP impact that? Also, I do not see a group by statement, so i am guessing there are 16 records that satisfy the filter and all your RecordCounts are 1. Right?

Comment: It is returning correct records but the value in "Recordcounts" is 16, wherein actual result is 3 rows only, so "Recordcounts" should be 3, but I don't konw how to get it.

Comment: Can you try this? SELECT distinct count(crs.CourseId) over(Partition by crs.CourseId) as Recordcounts, 
            crs.CourseId,
            crs.CourseName,
            crs.CourseDescription,
            (select CourseGroupName from CourseGroup cgrp where cgrp.CourseGroupId= crs.CourseGroupId) as Category
            FROM Courses crs 
            Inner join CourseRequests creq on crs.CourseId = creq.CourseId
            where crs.Coursename <> ''''

Comment: This screenshot will give more clear idea about problem:

Comment: The above suggestion did not work? I can't see a screenshot

Comment: Updated in question itself..

Comment: Well, there are 16 rows - but of those 16 rows, only 3 distinct sets of column values exist. Usually, if you're getting duplicate rows, it's better to find out *why* and to systematically eliminate them, rather than just slapping `DISTINCT` at the start of the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Suggestion not working...As per screenshot, I am expecting value 16 in "RecordCounts", but it giving 76, which is wrong, I think it is not checking for rest of the conditions, merely giving count of rows from the Course table.

Comment: #Damien_The_Unbeliever....no, these all are distinct results.

Comment: No, delete `DISTINCT` from the start of your query and you'll see 76 results rather than 16. Now you need to work out *why* you have so many duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as(
SELECT distinct
    crs.CourseId,
    crs.CourseName,
    crs.CourseDescription,
    (SELECT CourseGroupName FROM CourseGroup cgrp 
     WHERE cgrp.CourseGroupId = crs.CourseGroupId) AS Category
FROM 
    Courses crs 
INNER JOIN 
    CourseRequests creq ON crs.CourseId = creq.CourseId
WHERE
    crs.Coursename <> '''')

Select *, (select COUNT(CourseId) from cte) AS Recordcounts
from cte
```